# how to give interval in a program process using timer control c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, timer, intervals, time-wait

how can i give interval in a program process using timer control.

Like:

```
while(progressBar1.Value ! = 10)
{
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.value + 1;
   //i want to give 10 seconds interval here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

-Drag a Timer onto your form *or if its not winforms simply instantiate a Timer control in code.* 
-Click it and press F4 to bring up the properties.
-Set the Timers Interval property to 10000 *or programmatically `timer1.Interval = 10000;`*.
-Set the Enabled property to True *or programmatically `timer1.Enabled = true;`*.
-To view the Timers events click the lightning bolt icon (in the properties window)

Then double click the Tick event (the row in the property window called Tick). This will take you to the Timers_Tick event where you can add this code:

```
//This event will fire each 10 seconds
private void timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
{
 if (progressBar1.Value ! = 10)
 {
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.value + 1;
 }
}
```